# Trident OpaqueKafkaSpout: transactions not committed

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

So I'm using the storm-kafka-client to subscribe my topology to a Kafka topic. Since I need exactly-once semantics I'm using the Opaque Spout, however the first transaction is never committed, it gets saved to the state and then it's replayed over and over again periodically. If I push more data into Kafka, this data is not being saved to the state either because the previous transaction hasn't been commited. The State I'm using is the Kafka State as well.

I'm using Strom 1.2.1 and Kafka 1.0.1 if that matters.

edit: this is the topology I'm using.

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setNumWorkers(NUM_WORKERS);
conf.setDebug(true);
conf.setMaxSpoutPending(MAX_SPOUT_PENDING);

KafkaSpoutConfig.Builder<String, String> spoutConfig = KafkaSpoutConfig.builder(KAFKA_BROKERS, KAFKA_TOPIC);
spoutConfig.setProp(SchemaRegistryClient.Configuration.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL.name(), SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
spoutConfig.setProp(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
spoutConfig.setProp(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
spoutConfig.setProcessingGuarantee(KafkaSpoutConfig.ProcessingGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE);
spoutConfig.setFirstPollOffsetStrategy(KafkaSpoutConfig.FirstPollOffsetStrategy.UNCOMMITTED_EARLIEST);
spoutConfig.setOffsetCommitPeriodMs(5000);
KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque kafkaSpout = new KafkaTridentSpoutOpaque<> (spoutConfig.build());

TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BROKERS);
props.put("acks", "1");
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");


TridentKafkaStateFactory stateFactory = new TridentKafkaStateFactory()
        .withProducerProperties(props)
        .withKafkaTopicSelector(new DefaultTopicSelector("test"))
        .withTridentTupleToKafkaMapper(new FieldNameBasedTupleToKafkaMapper("parsed_value", "parsed_value"));

Stream tramasRedis = topology.newStream("KAFKA_TRAMAS", kafkaSpout).parallelismHint(KAFKA_SPOUT_PARALELLISM)
        .each(new Fields("key", "value"), new ReadRedisMessage(), new Fields("parsed_value"));
tramasRedis.partitionPersist(stateFactory, new Fields("parsed_value"), new TridentKafkaStateUpdater());

LocalCluster lc = new LocalCluster();
StormSubmitter.submitTopology(TOPOLOGY_NAME, conf, topology.build());
```

And this is what I get in the logs when I receive a message from Kafka in debug mode.

```
2018-11-26 08:20:16.166 o.a.s.d.task Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] Emitting: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS s1 [13:2, redis-tramas-fnet, 1, 0, null, {"original": "test1"}]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.167 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 5 tuple: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: s1, id: {}, [13:2, redis-tramas-fnet, 1, 0, null, {"original": "test1"}]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.168 o.a.s.d.task Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] Emitting direct: 5; spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS $coord-bg0 [13:2, 1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.168 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 5 tuple: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: $coord-bg0, id: {-7985297489562004428=1604111899640219309}, [13:2, 1]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.169 o.a.s.d.task Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] Emitting: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS __ack_ack [-7985297489562004428 3421159403193702831]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.169 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 3 tuple: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 3421159403193702831]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.169 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 5 TUPLE: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: s1, id: {}, [13:2, redis-tramas-fnet, 1, 0, null, {"original": "test1"}]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.169 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 6 TIME: -1 TUPLE: source: $spoutcoord-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:2, stream: $batch, id: {-7985297489562004428=4123209423349964546}, [13:2, [{partition=3, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=2, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=1, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=0, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=7, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=6, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=5, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=4, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=11, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=10, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=9, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=8, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=15, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=14, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=13, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=12, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.169 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: $spoutcoord-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:2, stream: $batch, id: {-7985297489562004428=4123209423349964546}, [13:2, [{partition=3, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=2, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=1, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=0, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=7, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=6, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=5, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=4, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=11, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=10, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=9, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=8, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=15, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=14, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=13, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=12, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}]] TASK: 6 DELTA: -1
2018-11-26 08:20:16.169 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-10-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[6 6] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 6 TUPLE: source: $spoutcoord-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:2, stream: $batch, id: {-1505053285028712763=8306088157808961249}, [14:2, [{partition=3, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=2, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=1, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=0, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=7, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=6, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=5, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=4, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=11, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=10, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=9, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=8, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=15, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=14, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=13, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}, {partition=12, topic=redis-tramas-fnet}]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.171 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 3 TUPLE: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 3421159403193702831]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.171 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 3 TIME: -1 TUPLE: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 3421159403193702831]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.171 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 3421159403193702831] TASK: 3 DELTA: -1
2018-11-26 08:20:16.175 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 5 TIME: 6 TUPLE: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: s1, id: {}, [13:2, redis-tramas-fnet, 1, 0, null, {"original": "test1"}]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.175 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: s1, id: {}, [13:2, redis-tramas-fnet, 1, 0, null, {"original": "test1"}] TASK: 5 DELTA: -1
2018-11-26 08:20:16.175 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 5 TUPLE: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: $coord-bg0, id: {-7985297489562004428=1604111899640219309}, [13:2, 1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.175 o.a.s.d.task Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] Emitting: b-0 __ack_ack [-7985297489562004428 1604111899640219309]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.176 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 3 tuple: source: b-0:5, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 1604111899640219309]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.176 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 5 TIME: -1 TUPLE: source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: $coord-bg0, id: {-7985297489562004428=1604111899640219309}, [13:2, 1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.176 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-14-b-0-executor[5 5] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS:6, stream: $coord-bg0, id: {-7985297489562004428=1604111899640219309}, [13:2, 1] TASK: 5 DELTA: -1
2018-11-26 08:20:16.177 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 3 TUPLE: source: b-0:5, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 1604111899640219309]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.178 o.a.s.d.task Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Emitting direct: 1; __acker __ack_ack [-7985297489562004428 37198]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.178 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 1 tuple: source: __acker:3, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 37198]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.178 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 3 TIME: -1 TUPLE: source: b-0:5, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 1604111899640219309]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.178 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: b-0:5, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 1604111899640219309] TASK: 3 DELTA: -1
2018-11-26 08:20:16.181 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 1 TUPLE: source: __acker:3, stream: __ack_ack, id: {}, [-7985297489562004428 37198]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.181 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] SPOUT Acking message -7985297489562004428 13:2
2018-11-26 08:20:16.561 o.a.s.d.task Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] Emitting: $mastercoord-bg0 $batch [88:1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.562 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 2 tuple: source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: $batch, id: {-5934215212694827955=1827497614943510587}, [88:1]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.562 o.a.s.d.task Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] Emitting: $mastercoord-bg0 __ack_init [-5934215212694827955 1827497614943510587 1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.562 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] TRANSFERING tuple [dest: 3 tuple: source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [-5934215212694827955 1827497614943510587 1]]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.563 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-4-$spoutcoord-spout-KAFKA_TRAMAS-executor[2 2] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 2 TUPLE: source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: $batch, id: {-5934215212694827955=1827497614943510587}, [88:1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.565 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Processing received message FOR 3 TUPLE: source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [-5934215212694827955 1827497614943510587 1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.565 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] BOLT ack TASK: 3 TIME: -1 TUPLE: source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [-5934215212694827955 1827497614943510587 1]
2018-11-26 08:20:16.565 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-6-__acker-executor[3 3] [INFO] Execute done TUPLE source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: __ack_init, id: {}, [-5934215212694827955 1827497614943510587 1] TASK: 3 DELTA: -1
```

Activating the DEBUG logging on the MasterCoordinator I get these errors periodically.

```
2018-11-28 10:57:44.614 o.a.s.t.t.MasterBatchCoordinator Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [DEBUG] Fail. [tx_attempt = 18:4], [tx_status = null], [MasterBatchCoordinator{_states=[org.apache.storm.trident.topology.state.TransactionalState@6168a033], _activeTx={3=3:3 <PROCESSING>, 4=4:3 <PROCESSING>, 5=5:3 <PROCESSING>, 6=6:3 <PROCESSING>}, _attemptIds={3=3, 4=3, 5=3, 6=3, 7=3, 8=3, 9=3, 10=3, 11=3, 12=3, 13=3, 14=4, 15=4, 16=3, 17=3, 18=4, 19=7, 20=7, 21=7, 22=7, 23=7, 24=7, 25=7, 26=7, 27=7, 28=7, 29=7, 30=7, 31=7, 32=7, 33=7, 34=7, 35=7, 36=7, 37=7, 38=7, 39=7, 40=7, 41=7, 42=7, 43=6, 44=6, 45=5, 46=5, 47=5, 48=5, 49=5, 50=6, 51=5, 52=5, 53=5, 54=5, 55=5, 56=5, 57=5, 58=5, 59=5, 60=5, 61=5, 62=5, 63=5, 64=5, 65=5, 66=5, 67=5, 68=4, 69=4, 70=4, 71=4, 72=4, 73=4, 74=4, 75=4, 76=3, 77=3, 78=1, 79=1, 80=1, 81=1, 82=1, 83=1, 84=2, 85=1, 86=1, 87=1, 88=1, 89=1, 90=1, 91=1, 92=1, 93=1, 94=1, 95=1, 96=1, 97=1, 98=1, 99=1, 100=1, 101=0, 102=0}, _collector=org.apache.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector@1f58e2fd, _currTransaction=3, _maxTransactionActive=100, _coordinators=[org.apache.storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor$Coordinator@6faffb26], _managedSpoutIds=[KAFKA_TRAMAS], _spouts=[org.apache.storm.trident.spout.OpaquePartitionedTridentSpoutExecutor@59e6917f], _throttler=org.apache.storm.utils.WindowedTimeThrottler@7d2bdb48, _active=true}]
2018-11-28 10:57:44.616 o.a.s.d.executor Thread-8-$mastercoord-bg0-executor[1 1] [INFO] SPOUT Failing -2574568553084235376: {:stream "$batch", :values [#object[org.apache.storm.trident.topology.TransactionAttempt 0x4fce1854 "19:6"]]} REASON: TIMEOUT MSG-ID: 19:6
```

Aparently the batches failing are empty. If there is data in the topic when the topology starts it works because there's no empty batches beforehand, however after the first batch is committed (the one with data), the empty batches start failing and new Kafka data is not being processed because there's uncommitted transactions. If the topic is empty, it just fails constantly and it doesn't push anything to Kafka.

Comment: Is it the storm-kafka or storm-kafka-client spout?

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing it's the storm-kafka-client

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the worker logs? The State should log if it fails to write to Kafka. Also try posting your topology setup.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing updated the post with more info. I don't get any writing failure. Actually it only saves the first batch if there's already data in the topic when i run the topology. If the topic is empty and I push data when the topology is running, it doesn't write that batch either.

Comment: The log you posted is helpful, but I think we need to enable debug logging for the master batch coordinator (the component that controls emit/commit behavior in Trident, you can see it in the log named something like $mastercoord). Could you enable debug logging for org.apache.storm.trident.topology.MasterBatchCoordinator and try again?

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing updated the post with the errors I found on the logs. I didn't post the full log because it's pretty big.

Comment: Try to find out which tuple was emitted and not acked. Your logs shows that the tuple anchor id is -2574568553084235376. If you check the log, you should be able to tell which tuples were emitted with that anchor. It should look something like "Processing received message FOR 2 TUPLE: source: $mastercoord-bg0:1, stream: $batch, id: {-2574568553084235376=1827497614943510587}, [88:1]". You can use this to tell why the tuple is timing out, since the log will also show acks being sent from each bolt to the master coordinator.

Comment: Also if you have the opportunity, you should consider trying out Storm 2.0.0. The storm-kafka-client Trident spout has been partially reworked in that version, it might be worth seeing if that version is showing the same behavior.